# Which God has title of 'Adipurush'?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, rama

I thought, it is a term associated with Lord Shiva since he is known as Adiyogi too but a Ramayan adaptation movie is using it for Lord Ram.

Answer (score 2):

'*Adipurush*', according to *[vedic sources](https://vedicsources.com/the-complete-list-of-24-avatars-of-lord-vishnu/),* was the first avatar of Vishnu. He

> is considered as the first man of this universe...He is depicted in yellow garments, has four hands, and in one hand he has the Sudarshana chakra. He sleeps on the curls of a serpent, *Sheshnag*.

And according to *[shloka preneur divya](https://www.shlokapreneurdivyaa.com/the-avatar-of-lord-vishnu/)*,

> The Puranas mention that AdiPurush refers to the first incarnation of Lord Vishnu, who is regarded as the creator of the universe. It is believed that after creating the universe, He took his first incarnation as the pre-eminent man and is referred to as the first man of this universe, hence he is known as Adipurush. He is regarded as supreme and the epitome of goodness and righteousness. Over the years, He is believed to have taken various forms in order to kill evil and protect the universe.

(*Adi Purush* means *first man*)

Comment: Thankyou for answering!

Comment: @Rambhakt - No problem, I hope that it helped you  :)